# Will struts 1.2.4 work with Java5?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

As of now we are using Struts1.2.4 with java4. We want to upgrade it to Java5. Java 5 has so 
[many deprecated method in EE](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/deprecated-list.html). Will struts 1.2.4 work with java 5?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Java 4", please clarify what you're using now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that although they're deprecated, they *still* will exist/function as before. Deprecation just means that they will disappear in a future edition.

Regardless of the deprecation, I would schedule some serious testing just to make ensure behaviour hasn't changed (I do this for all platform migrations, no matter how trivial).

Comment: I think EE6 will be the first time that some features actually disappear, right? EE5 contains all the baggage from the original J2EE, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think Java 1.5 itself should be okay, but if you are running struts 1.2.4, it seems to me that your app may have other dependencies that are quite old as well. Servlet container version (tomcat 4?) is one thing that comes to my mind. If it's worth-while to upgrade to Java 1.5, it may also be worth-while to move to struts 1.3.9 or even struts2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've used it on previous projects and can't even think of any major caveats. If I were you, I'd give it a quick test. You should be fine.